# Javascript runs when in <script>, but not from .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to figure out why my javascript code will run raw in `<script>...code...</script>`, but not with the code in a file like:

```
<SCRIPT SRC="http://website.com/download/others/wiredtriangle.js" LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" type="text/javascript">
```

Im also running

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried wrapping the code in the file with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

But it didn't make a difference.

Here is the actual code: https://jsfiddle.net/y2qct6nf/

Comment: HTML tags should be written in all lower case, and `language` and `type` are not needed in newer browsers. Remove those attributes and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Your fiddle seems fine. Is the problem on your local version? If so, ensure you've included your `<script>` tag *after* the one which references jQuery

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Have you tried https instead of http?

Comment: any errors in your console? inline script after the src?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn _"HTML tags should be written in all lower case"_ Tag names can be written in either lowercase or uppercase

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You should delete that comment as it's just expressing your opinion, but you're saying it as if it's a fact.  "Should" does not mean "can".  If you'd have put "can" then your comment would have made no sense.

Comment: Any errors in the devtool-console? If you're running it by directly opening the HTML-File in the Browser, on some modern Browsers it may not execute JS. Did you try to open a local server?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

Comment: The `language` attribute is deprecated. which could be breaking it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Deprecated_attributes

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn You do have a valid point as to the `language` attribute at `<script>` elements, though MDN is not the [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features), though note that the attribute is still a part of  HTML _"The following attributes are obsolete (though the elements are still part of the language)"_ _"language on script elements (except as noted in the previous section)
Omit the attribute for JavaScript; for data blocks, use the type attribute instead."_

Comment: figured it out, had to edit a few things in the .js: http://fiddle.jshell.net/y2qct6nf/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){ ...code... }//]]>
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/y2qct6nf/3/

Comment: not sure why `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` didn't work but this did